# DwmIsCompositionEnabed is not present in afxglobals.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, migration

I've a project compiled in VS2010. It compiles and executes well.

The same project, if compiled in VS2012, throws the following error :

`C2039 : DwmIsCOmpositionEnabled is not a member of AFX_GLOBAL_DATA`

Checking online, some people have reported the error with the cause being installations of multiple VS environments.

However, my machine is a clean install, and there is only VS2012 Professional installed.

Checking the header file, this function is indeed not present in `AfxGlobals.h`.

What should I be checking to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Breaking Changes in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for VS2012, under the MFC/ATL section you will see (among others):

> Renamed **AFX_GLOBAL_DATA::DwmIsCompositionEnabled** to **IsDwmCompositionEnabled** to eliminate name collision.

I suggest you change your source code accordingly.

Comment: Ahh..yes. I get it. Hadn't checked it. Thanks for pointing it out to me. I've made the necessary changes. It is working fine.